# C to MIPS assembly language

Tags: c, assembly, mips, computer-science

`i` and `j` are assigned to registers `$s3` and `$s4` and the base address of `A` and `B` are in registers `$s6` and `$s7`.

```
B [8] = A [i-j]
```

So the answer is something like

```
sub $t0, $s3, $s4
add $t0, $s6, $t0
lw $t1, 16($t0)   (What is happening here.. I am so confused)
sw $t1, 32($s7)
```

Please explain. I am so confused

Comment: What are the types of A and B?

Answer (score 1):

My MIPS assembly is rusty, but...

lw/sw are load word/store word.

syntax being lw register, address

So for the instruction you indicated, the address in $t0 is being loaded into $t1. The 16 thing is a notation to add 16 to $t0 before the load word instruction.

Comment: Yeah but Why 16 and why not 32?

Comment: the 32 is the offset based on B [8]. It isn't as clear what the 16 is from but it has to do with the alignment of your variables/structures.

Comment: The 16 offset is wrong, you should see @markgz answer

Comment: @Robert: Based on the title I assume he is converting from C to Assembly, so I doubt that the code is wrong. C compiler is free to do many optimizations so it is just as likely the result is due to some optimization or portion of the C program we are not able to see.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks incorrect:

```
sub $t0, $s3, $s4  # t0 = i -j
# there should be a "sll $t0, 2" here to convert i-j to a byte offset
add $t0, $s6, $t0  # t0 += &A
lw $t1, 16($t0)    # this line is incorrect - it should be lw t1,($t0) with no offset
sw $t1, 32($s7)    # store t1 at &B + 8 words i.e. 32 bytes
```